# Integrating a Filter() with an Alert Snippet

Tags: javascript, filter, alert

I suspect this is not so difficult, but it’s driving me crazy.

After the filter method leaves either a string or an empty string, I want an alert to reflect which came out.

Here is the closest I have gotten:

```
function wordCheck(wordInput) {
    var wordList = ["sad tissue","thirsty drink"];
    var wordResult = "";
    var wordInput = wordInput.toLowerCase().trim();
    var filtered = "";

    filtered = wordList.filter(function(val){
       return val == wordInput;
    });
    wordResult = filtered.join(""); 
    return wordResult;
}

function wordAlert(filtered) {
    if (filtered == "") {
        alert("Try Again, Kiddo!");
    } else {
        alert("Good job!");
    }
}

var filtered = wordCheck();

wordAlert(filtered);
```

Thank you @Nisarg Shah and @Naren Murali. That input was very helpful.

I was amazed to get so much help so quickly!

Unfortunately, I don’t think I described the situation well enough.

There is a form in my HTML with a text box and a check button:

```
<input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "word_pair"><br>
<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Check This!" onclick = "wordCheck();">
```

Students have a list of adj. and nouns to match. They choose two, input them, and click the button.

I want wordCheck() to do 4 things: (1) check that the words match the pair list & if they do, (2) cross off the words on the list; then (3) drop the words into the value = "" section of a text box, where the students will write sentences based on the words. eg. "thirsty water” -> “He looks thirsty. Give him some water.” (4) Wrong answers will get an alert ("Try Again!").

I was thinking that if I could solve a simple alert problem, then adding other functionality would be simple. (I hope I'm being realistic...)

With your help, the code got much farther in the PythonTutor.com code checker, but now Google Chrome hates my .toLowerCase, saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

Or, if I comment the .toLowerCase() line out, the alerts fire off almost randomly.

You guys got me much farther, to be sure; and that was a great help.

I changed the original busted code to reflect somewhat better code.

I just thought I’d give you a thorough update, since you were so thoughtful.

If I get anywhere with this, I’ll let you know.

THX!

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

1. `filtered` is local to `wordCheck` function, so it cannot be accessed inside `wordAlert`.
2. These quotes `“` will result in incorrect syntax errors as they are not recognized by Javascript. Instead use `'` or `"`.

I've also replaced `return wordResult = filtered.join("");` with two statements to improve clarity, and replaced two `if(filtered == '')` and `if(filtered != '')` conditions with and `if...else`.

Also, I don't see any need for `wordResult = filtered.join("");` at the end, since you can check if any element was returned by checking `wordResult.length > 0`. But I have left it in the snippet below for now.

```js
function wordCheck(wordInput) {
    var wordList = ['sneeze bleshu','fart omg'];
    var wordResult = '';
    var wordInput = wordInput.toLowerCase().trim();
    var filtered = '';

    filtered = wordList.filter(function(val){
       return val == wordInput;
    });
    
    wordResult = filtered.join("");
    return wordResult;
}

function wordAlert(filtered) {
    if (filtered == '') {
        alert('Try Again, Kiddo!');
    } else {
        alert('Good job!');
    }
}

var result = wordCheck('sneeze bleshu');
wordAlert(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I clarified some things in the original post, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, I replace the quotes `“”` because they seem invalid characters.

The problem with your code is, the variable `filtered` is defined inside the function, so it will not be visible in another function, instead please define it outside the function, so that is visible to all the functions.

Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

```js
var filtered = "";
function wordCheck(wordInput) {
    var wordList = ["sneeze bleshu","fart omg"];
    var wordResult = "";
    var wordInput = wordInput.toLowerCase().trim();

    filtered = wordList.filter(function(val){
       return val == wordInput;
    });
    return wordResult = filtered.join("");
}

function wordAlert() {
    if (filtered == "") {
        alert("Try Again, Kiddo!");
    }
    if (filtered !== "") {
        alert("Good job!");
    }
}

wordCheck("sneeze bleshu");

wordAlert();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I explained some other things in the original post, above, too.